Toast In PHP native not working on Success Side
I have this code in my PHP server side block that defines the TOAST functionality

 // Define the HTML code for the toast element
echo '<div class="toastNotif hide">
    <div class="toast-content">
        <i class="bx bx-check check"></i>
        <div class="message">
            <span class="text text-1"></span>
            <!-- this message can be changed to "Success" and "Error"-->
            <span class="text text-2"></span>
            <!-- specify based on the if-else statements -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <i class="bx bx-x close"></i>
    <div class="progress"></div>
</div>';

// Define JavaScript functions to handle the toast
echo '<script>
    function showToast(type, message) {
        var toast = document.querySelector(".toastNotif");
        var progress = document.querySelector(".progress");
        var text1 = toast.querySelector(".text-1");
        var text2 = toast.querySelector(".text-2");
        
        if (toast && progress && text1 && text2) {
            // Update the toast content based on the message type
            if (type === "success") {
                text1.textContent = "Success";
                toast.classList.remove("error");
            } else if (type === "error") {
                text1.textContent = "Error";
                toast.classList.add("error");
            } else {
                console.error("Invalid message type");
                return;
            }
            
            // Set the message content
            text2.textContent = message;
            
            // Show the toast and progress
            toast.classList.add("showing");
            progress.classList.add("showing");
            
            // Hide the toast and progress after 5 seconds
            setTimeout(() => {
                toast.classList.remove("showing");
                progress.classList.remove("showing");
                 window.location.href = "staff_log.php";
            }, 5000);
        } else {
            console.error("Toast elements not found");
        }
    }

    function closeToast() {
        var toast = document.querySelector(".toastNotif");
        var progress = document.querySelector(".progress");
        toast.classList.remove("showing");
        progress.classList.remove("showing");
    }
</script>';

This code does work on this Error Trapping
// Check if the form is submitted and Borrower ID is provided
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['borrower_id'])) {
    // Database connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "db_library_2", 3308); 
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }


    // Retrieve Borrower_ID from the form
    $borrower_id = $_POST['borrower_id'];
    if (substr($borrower_id, 0, 1) === '0') {
        // Borrower_ID starts with '0', flag as error
          echo '<script>
    // Call showToast with "error" message type after encountering an error
    showToast("error", "Error Entry.");
</script>';

    } 

However on the success side the TOAST does not show the UI and just display Success then redirect as it should be after 5 seconds,
 else {
            // Validate Borrower_ID against tbl_borrower table
            $sql_validate_borrower = "SELECT * FROM tbl_borrower WHERE Borrower_ID = '$borrower_id'";
            $result_validate_borrower = $conn->query($sql_validate_borrower);

            if ($result_validate_borrower->num_rows > 0) {
                // Borrower_ID is valid
                $isBorrowerIdValid = true;
                $_SESSION['borrower_id'] = $borrower_id;

                // SQL query to insert data with auto-increment Log_ID and current timestamp
                $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_log (Borrower_ID, `Date_Time`) 
                VALUES ($borrower_id, NOW())";

                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    // echo '<script>alert("Record inserted successfully."); window.location.href = "staff_log.php";</script>';
                 echo '<script>
        // Call showToast with "success" message type after successful insertion
        showToast("success", "Record inserted successfully.");
    </script>';


it does not display the UI with the success "Record Inserted Succesfully"
but display showToast Error on the error trapping code line
i have tried this code on other page and the success does show with it's appropriate styling
Did i mess something up or what
i wanted to display the success on this page yet it does not show with the styling

Any errors in the browser's console? Does the PHP code definitely reach and execute the  echo '<script>         // Call showToast with "success" message type after successful insertion         showToast("success", "Record inserted successfully."); line? Have you done any debugging? We can't run this code so you need to be more specific / technical about the exact issue.

@ADyson yes sir, i did try to put console log and when i input the correct data, it does reach at that code, only the success code toast are not working, the error does work with no problem
there is no error showned on the browser console upon on this section,

@ADyson im sorry HAHAHA i just realized that i put exit(); on this code
     if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                // echo '<script>alert("Record inserted successfully."); window.location.href = "staff_log.php";</script>';
             echo '<script>
    // Call showToast with "success" message type after successful insertion
    showToast("success", "Record inserted successfully.");
</script>';

                // exit();
            }

when i comment it, the banner showed HAHA Thank you anyways

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

im sorry i just realized that i put exit(); on this code
     if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                // echo '<script>alert("Record inserted successfully."); window.location.href = "staff_log.php";</script>';
             echo '<script>
    // Call showToast with "success" message type after successful insertion
    showToast("success", "Record inserted successfully.");
</script>';

                // exit(); ------ THIS ONE IS THE ONE FAILING THE TOAST
            }

when i comment it, the banner showed

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
